# How do I prove that this set is closed in $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

The set is $$\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} : y \in \{\pm \sqrt{x}\}\}$$

I have tried to see if the complement is open but this example is tricky and I would like to ask for some help on how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: hint: this set is the graph of a continous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+} $

Answer (score 2):

Prescribe $f:\mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by: $$\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x-y^2$$

It can be shown to be continuous so that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ as preimage of a closed set will be closed.

Now observe that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the set mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is more easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For the set $S=\{(x,y)\in{\bf{R}}_{+}\times{\bf{R}}: y=\sqrt{x}\}=\{(x,\sqrt{x}): x\in{\bf{R}}_{+}\}$, if $(x_{n},\sqrt{x_{n}})\in S$ is such that $(x_{n},\sqrt{x_{n}})\rightarrow(x,y)$, then $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, and the continuity of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ gives $\sqrt{x_{n}}\rightarrow\sqrt{x}$, but $\sqrt{x_{n}}\rightarrow y$, so $y=\sqrt{x}$, so $(x,y)=(x,\sqrt{x})\in S$.

Comment: even in the second case the set is closed in the subspace topology as it is the intersection of the closed set from the first case with the space of the second case, is it not?

Comment: You are right, I messed up with the completeness.

Comment: I do mean by $R_+$ the set $[0, \infty)$. Thanks.